# Is the local ring $(K[x_1,...,x_n,...])_{(x_1,...,x_n)}$ noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian, localization

If $K$ is a field, $A=K[x_1,...,x_n,...]$ (countably many variables) and $p=(x_1,...,x_n)\subset A$, I'm trying to prove or disprove that $A_{p}$ is noetherian.

I'm trying to argue that if $J\subsetneq A_p$, there exists $I\subset p$ such that $J=IA_p$ and the fact that $I\subset p$ allows us to conclude that $I$ is finitely generated.

Is this true? How can I see this?

Comment: Let $L$ be the fraction field of $K[x_{n+1},x_{n+2},\ldots]$ and show that $A_p$ is just $L[x_1,\ldots,x_n]_{(x_1,\ldots, x_n)}$.